# RasPi2 Samba Compile

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, samba

I'm attempting a samba-3.6.24 compile with the new Raspberry Pi 2 using flags:

```
export CC=gcc
export CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp"
```

I'm crashing with:

```
  error: bin/smbd uses VFP register 
  arguments, ../auth/auth_sam_reply.o does not
```

Thanks for any help!  BTW, the RPi2 is a lot of fun; I'm running debian jessie and performance has been pretty snappy. Compiling dropbear took a little over a minute and busybox took about 5.

Comment: try using : `-mfloat-abi=softfp`

Comment: Won't configure with softfp.